# Making Textbox visible if combobox contains a specific value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, textbox, visibility

I have a combo box with a list of mobile tariffs in and a service credit textbox (Not Visible) that the sales agent will fill in. What i need to know is, how do i make the service credit textbox visible IF the combobox contains the word "Resign"?

Thanks

Comment: `txtServiceCredit.Visible=(cboTariffs.Text="Resign")` or the like? That said, you should always post some code, show that you've actually tried something.

Answer (score 0):

Use the after update event of the form https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822097.aspx then use the controls visible property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258163(v=office.12).aspx